# How to update password for a specific user for data in flowfiles

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

sample flowfile data:

```
  "v3_users" : [ {
    "username" : "user1",
    "password" : "password1",
    "privacy_password" : "privacy1"
  }, {
    "username" : "user2",
    "password" : "password2",
    "privacy_password" : "privacy2",
    "engineId" : "801020308"
  },{
    "privacy_password" : "privacy_password4",
    "username" : "user4",
    "password" : "password4",
    "engineId" : "801020305"
  } ],
  "v2_communities" : [ "community1", "community2" ]"
}
```

There are multiple queues of user data, For suppose a user1 wants to change his password, how to update the password  for that user .Is there any nifi native processor or is it possible to achieve through jolt transformation?